# trigonometry finding 2 possible $\cos$ values of an angle

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

In a triangle $ABC$, $AB = 10$ cm and $AC= 5$ cm. The area is $15$ cm${}^2$ and the angle $BAC$ is equal to $\theta$.

Give two possible values of $\cos(\theta)$.

I was able to find one of the values of $\cos(\theta)$ which is 0.8 but how can I get a second value for $\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: Format? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: How did you get the first value?

Comment: 15 = 0.5*10*5*sin(θ)  solve for θ and then do the cos inverse of θ which is equal to 0.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area of the triangle will be equal to 
$$\frac{(AB)(AC)\sin\theta}{2}$$
meaning that $\sin\theta=0.6$, as you probably found. This means that
$$\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta=0.64$$
and 
$$\cos\theta=\color{green}{\pm}0.8$$
The positive value corresponds to $\theta$ an acute angle, and then negative value corresponds to obtuse $\theta$.

Comment: thanks that make a lot more sense now didn`t know you had to apply a trigonometry identity there

Comment: @johnsmith Great! If it helped, don't forget to $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$! :)